# Google apps script: view PDF in deployed web app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-apps-script, iframe

I am a beginner trying to build a web app that helps automate work processes and leverage data from my business.

I'm building a web app in Google Apps Script. What I would like to do is view a PDF from a (third party) link in a gSheet. To do so I am trying to use the PDFObject.js utility (https://pdfobject.com/). So far I am successfully:

1. My web app is deploying OK and showing up correctly from Google Apps Script
2. Drawing out the PDF *link* out of the gSheet.
3. Using jQuery to access the correct div element to display the PDF viewer:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pure-u-3-4', function(){
       PDFObject.embed("<<PDF URL for gSheet>>", "#main-content-content");
});
```

I am getting an error on the page *in Chrome*. It shows up correctly in Edge. The error I am getting on the console is:

> Failed to load `'<<PDF URL>>'` as a plugin, because the frame into which the plugin is loading is sandboxed.

I assume this has to do with Chrome and plug-ins, but I'm not sure how to fix or correctly search for my problem. My preferred browser is Chrome, so I would really like to figure out how to fix. Any help, or points to a similar question that could answer my problem, would be greatly appreciated!